# SystemVerilog Interface data type with list of instance names

Tags: system-verilog

`be_nl_i` and `xbc_i` are interface modules. Code example A with a list of instance names compiles.

Example A

```
be_nl_i be_nl0 (), be_nl1 ();
```

However, example B with another interface data type does not compile.

Example B

```
xbc_i #(.NUM(3)) xbc0 (clk), #(.NUM(3)) xbc0_d1 (clk), #(.NUM(3)) xbc0_d2 (clk);
```

Is there a proper syntax to compile example B?

Answer (score 2):

Parameter overrides of a module is not instance specific.

```
xbc_i #(.NUM(3)) xbc0 (clk), xbc0_d1 (clk),  xbc0_d2 (clk);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the single line declaration doesn't go well with modules/interface.
Following code should work.

```
    xbc_i #(.NUM(3)) xbc0 (clk);
    xbc_i #(.NUM(3)) xbc0_d1 (clk); 
    xbc_i #(.NUM(3)) xbc0_d2 (clk);
```